# OSX: Launching window from status bar menu

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindowcontroller, nspopover, nsstatusbar

I have a status bar app that runs as an Agent, with no dock icon or main window. When you click the status bar icon a popover shows up(think Dropbox) and it has a button. This button needs to launch a window for the app. So essentially when you start your computer the app starts quietly and sits in your status bar and doesn't open any ui until you launch it from the popover. I'm having trouble launching the view/viewcontroller from the main.storyboard via the view controller for my popover(which is it's own separate nib).

I came across one answer that said to try the following:

```
- (IBAction)LaunchButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSStoryboard *storyBoard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; // get a reference to the storyboard
    myController = [storyBoard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];       // instantiate your window controller
    [myController showWindow:nil];
}
```

However this isn't working as instantiateControllerWithIdentifier is returning a viewController not a windowViewController. Any ideas on how to go about this? There isn't much information lying around about status bar apps. I'm familiar with iOS programming but this is my first attempt at an OSX app.

The app is currently very small so I can provide more source code if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is "Is Initial Controller" checked on the window controller within the "Main" storyboard?  It will create a "Storyboard Entry Point" item in the window controller scene.

Comment: Turns out there was a Window Controller AND a view controller both with an ID of Main... Ooops!